# MySQL - selecting rows around a certain row criteria

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select just the neighboring N and M rows before and after a certain row criteria, for a high scores table that focuses on the user's personal score (compared with players with similar scores N above and M below).

```
scores
-------
id:int
username:varchar(120)
score:int
```

**Note: each username has multiple scores. The high scores database is simply a score dump**

So, to fetch just the top 10 global scores: `SELECT max(score),username FROM scores GROUP BY username, ORDER BY score DESC`

However, I'm trying to do this for any arbitrary user - most of which aren't lucky enough to fall in the top 10...

How do I reference the N rows above and M rows below a certain user's score, in order to pull 10 scores above and below a user's score?

Comment: Do you want users max score to be included in result as well? And what should happen if user has many max results (which one should be used to count N and M)?

Answer (score 3):

To get the N results above the user, assuming all scores are distinct:

```
select s.*
from scores
where s.score > (select s.score from scores where username = $username)
order by score desc
limit N;
```

To get the M scores less than a given users score:

```
select s.*
from scores
where s.score < (select s.score from scores where username = $username)
order by score asc
limit M;
```

Having identical scores poses a little challenge.  The following combines the above two with a `union all` and fixes this problem:

```
(select s.*
 from scores s cross join
      (select * from scores where username = $username) u
 where s.score > u.score or
       s.score = u.score and s.id > u.id
 order by s.score desc, s.id desc
 limit N
) union all
(select s.*
 from scores s cross join
      (select * from scores where username = $username) u
 where s.score < u.score or
       s.score = u.score and s.id < u.id
 order by s.score, s.id
 limit M
)
```